# SCSS effects not showing in React jsx component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to style a React component but I can't see the effect. There isn't any error, just there are no styles.

ButtonFilled.jsx (my React component)

```
import React from 'react';
import css from './button.scss';

class ButtonFilled extends React.Component {
   render() {

      return (

          <div>
         <button className = {css.buttonFilled}>
            Learn More
         </button>
          </div>
      );
   }
}
   export default ButtonFilled;
```

button.scss (my stylesheet)

```
@import "base.scss";
.buttonFilled{
     font-size: 24;
     color: '#6D0839';
     font-weight: "bold";
     background-color: '#FFFFFF';
     padding-top: 17;
     padding-bottom: 22;
     padding-left: 15;
     padding-right: 15;
     width: 203;
     border-radius: 5;
     border-color: '#FFFFFF';
  }
```

Why is this happening? Am I not specifying the class name correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import it this way.

```
import React from 'react';
import './button.scss';

class ButtonFilled extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
          <div>
            <button className = "buttonFilled">
              Learn More
            </button>
          </div>
      );
   }
}

export default ButtonFilled;
```

Comment: Error must be from how sass is bundled in your webpack config

Comment: Please check you webpack configuration. You might not have added the scss-loader.

Answer (score 0):

Where is button.scss located ? If its the same folder with ButtonFilled.jsx i dont see anything wrong. Otherwise change the path to the correct one, kindly note the . in  './button.scss' means current folder. Other way to use the css is just import the css like  `import'./button.scss';` (make sure its the right path). and on your jsx className="buttonFilled"